# Cell Style not working for a column Definition with pivot true in angular Ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using Ag grid to show data to end user's, below is my column definition, I am using cell style property for fact name column but I see it is not working. Anyone please tell me where I am making mistake.

```
[
  {
    "field": "name",
    "rowGroup": true,
    "enableRowGroup": true,
    "width": 150
  },
  {
    "field": "group",
    "pivot": true,
    "width": 150
  },
  {
    "field": "factname",
    "pivot": true,
    "width": 150,
    "cellStyle": {"color": "red", "background-color": "green"}
  },
  {
    "field": "value",
    "aggFunc": "first",
    "width": 180
  }
]
```

Comment: I think, there is global style conflict.

Comment: @Lovely I have not added any global style

Comment: Can I see your project result on any host?

Comment: @Lovely you can check it under this link https://plnkr.co/edit/pdKyFbNHUwcDS37b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this sample I've forked from yours: https://plnkr.co/edit/VGfDbRN7dgrmWW8V

Fixes:

1. I'm assuming you want to cell style on the pivoted columns that are generated, for this you should apply your cellStyle on the column `value` because you are aggregating on that column:

```
      {
        headerName: 'Value',
        field: 'value',
        cellStyle: { color: 'red', 'background-color': 'green' },
        aggFunc: 'first',
      },
```

2. in `index.html` on line 106-107 you are importing styles which don't exist and are conflicting with the grid styles. I've commented these out so now it works.

Comment: I am trying to color the column definitions

Comment: What do you mean by "column definitions". Do you mean the column headers?

Comment: You can do this via CSS / SCSS as shown in the documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/themes-customising/#full-list-of-theme-parameters

See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-rxs7xd?file=src%2Fstyles.scss